# Scikit-learn Gaussiannb on dataframe with lots of string variables

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gaussian, naivebayes

So I have been trying to build a Naive Baynes prediction on a dataframe like this to predict Target (1/ 0) based on 3 categorical variables:

```
Target  ConsumerType    MostSigWeekday  MostSigDayPart
  1             c             Monday           Morning
  1             y             Friday           Morning
  0             bb            Sunday           Morning
  1             ki           Thursday          Evening
  0            yoe            Monday           Evening
```

The problem I have is that the function GaussianNB() do not like string:

```
features = MS3.columns[0:2]
target = np.asarray(file['Target'], dtype = "int")
# tar estimator
tar = GaussianNB()
model = tar.fit(MS3[features], target)
y_tar = model.predict(MS3[features])

ValueError: could not convert string to float: Monday
```

So as it goes, I have tried to build a CountVector by stack all these variables into one - ['MostSig']:

```
MostSigonly = pivoted_data['MostSig']
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
vect = CountVectorizer() 
train = vect.fit_transform(MostSigonly)
```

This vectorizerization step works and the GaussianNB does give out some results, but instead of comparing all three columns, the model predicts on individual variables and I get something non-sense like this:

```
model2 = GaussianNB()
trained = model2.fit(train_data,target)
c_pred = trained.predict(train_data)

print("Number of mislabeled points out of a total %d points : %d" \
      % (train_data.shape[0],(target != c_pred).sum()))
```

**Number of mislabeled points out of a total 47121 points : 30839**

My Question is, how could I vectorize the variables correctly? 
Or more broadly asking, how should I approach the problem?

Sorry for an open end questions by I have been searching for days but still has no clues to tackle the task.

Many Thanks in advance!